# Div encroaching into another column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a slight issue with a comment box that I have made.
So the comments get loaded but some comments are really long and have some characters that I suspect are making the comment box to be very wide and stretched. Normally the width is fine and wrapping works, just some comments cause this.

```
<div class="comments-group list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
        Top Comments
      </h4>
    </a>
    <span *ngFor="let item of getCurrentMediaList();let i = index ">
      <span *ngIf="i === currentIndex">
        <a class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let comment of item.comments;let x = index ">

          <span>
            <p>
              {{ comment }}
            </p>
          </span>    
        </a>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [small screenshot](https://postimg.org/image/seq054ecn/) of what it looks like when the comment area is stretched.

What I am trying to do is just ensure this div does not exceed the column even if the content within exceeds, in that case it should just wrap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I added the following to the div around the comments to fit it:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
-ms-word-break: break-all;
/* This is the dangerous one in WebKit, as it breaks things wherever */
word-break: break-all;
/* Instead use this non-standard one: */
word-break: break-word;

/* Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) */
-ms-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```